# JQuery Overlay loads only one time

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

The overlay loads when the user submits a form.. then the dialog appears (doing some validations and so on).. when the user close it, to continue working on the form.. CAN'T SUBMIT AGAIN the form. :(

This is the fragment of code, with some suggestions of control.. Can U help me? Thanx

```
            <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#subtitulo img[title]").tooltip();

                var overlay = $("#overlay"), adOver = {};
                    overlay.overlay({
                        top: 100,
                        mask: {
                            color: '#fff',
                            loadSpeed: 200,
                            opacity: 0.5
                        },
                        closeOnClick: false,
                        load: false,
                        onClose: function() {

                        }
                    });
                adOver = overlay.data('overlay');

                $('#form, #myform').submit( function() {

                    /*$("#overlay").overlay({
                        top: 100,
                        mask: {
                            color: '#fff',
                            loadSpeed: 200,
                            opacity: 0.5
                        },
                        closeOnClick: false,
                        load: true
                    });*/

                    adOver.load();
                    $('#overlayinfo').html('<p><img src=../imagenes/tooltip/loader.gif /></p>');
                    $('#overlayinfo').load('<?= $datosServ[carpeta] ?>/overlay/add.php','add=1&'+sendObjValues('myform'));
                    return false;   
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your submit event, you are returning false. This will prevent the default action of the event (submitting the form) and also stop propagation of the event to other listening functions.

Assuming there is some condition you have the requires the overlay, you can use the jquery event methods to prevent the default action, only when you are displaying the overlay.

```
$('#form, #myform').submit( function(evt) {
  if(showOverlay){
    evt.preventDefault();
    adOver.load();
    // or you could return false here
  }
}
```

Comment: We R loading the overlay inside the if validation.. when we ask if it is showing. :( didn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a callback to your $('').load function

$('#form, #myform').submit(function () {

```
    $("#overlay").overlay({
    top: 100,
    mask: {
    color: '#fff',
    loadSpeed: 200,
    opacity: 0.5
    },
    closeOnClick: false,
    load: true
    });

    adOver.load();
    $('#overlayinfo').html('<p><img src=../imagenes/tooltip/loader.gif /></p>');
    $('#overlayinfo').load('<?= $datosServ[carpeta] ?>/overlay/add.php', 'add=1&'+sendObjValues('myform'), function() {
        $("#overlay").overlay("close");
    });
    return false;
});
```